# parsing UItextfield for incorrect format of entry

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to get users to enter:

```
xyz http://www.example.org
```

in a textfield. But if they enter "http://www.example.org", I want to alert them immediately so they can add the "xyz" part ahead of it.

Whats the best way in Swift (2.x) to do  this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
let text = textField.text

if text.hasPrefix("xyz") {
    // you're good 
} else {
   // give alert 
}
```